# sending packets but not receiving in local area network

Tags: windows, networking

My local area network connection is sending packets but not receiving any packets. This causes my system unable to connect and access internet.

I am using windows xp service pack 3.

Comment: Not being able to connect to the internet with an XP machine is quite an okay solution... "Extended support for Windows XP ended on April 8, 2014 meaning that the operating system is now end-of-life, and new security updates or support information will no longer be provided for free."

Comment: Besides that and on a more serious note: it's borderline impossible to help you with the amount of information given. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and consider moving this question to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This may be a fault with your wall jack and LAN cable is not contacted properly. please remove it once and plugin again since you get a notification 'Local Area Network is connected' in your task bar. Before you can have that LAN connected, it is because you have connected your LAN in RJ-45 port (LAN cable port).

Try it! I fixed this problem like this.